# How to pre populate my custom form in magento

Tags: magento

I've created a custom form, similar to a customer registration form,  in `Magento`.
i want to prepopulate this form when an error messages arises.

Does anyone know how I can prepopulate a custom form in `Magento`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing you code it is hard to say which method will method will work, but one of these method should work.

**Using JavaScript Validation** - client side validate, only post if all require info is correct

```
<form name="my-form" id="my-form" method="post">
<label for="username">
< ?php echo $this->__("User name") ?> <span>*</span></label><br />
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="input-text required-entry"/>
.....
</form>

<script type=”text/javascript”>
//< ![CDATA[
var customForm = new VarienForm('my-form');
//]]>
</script>
```

See a list of all the [validation class name](http://www.9magentothemes.com/forums/threads/259-form-validation-in-magento)

**Repopulate field**
To get a list of all the post variable information that the customer fill out

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
```

To get a form field (eg. `<input type='text' name='firstname' ... />`)

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('firstname');
```

So in you .phtml try (this will not work if you doing a redirect on error)

```
<input type='text' name='firstname' value="<?php echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('firstname');?>" />
```

If the above doesnt work then you need the save the post info into a session.

In your controller if validation fail save the information to customer session

```
 Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->setData( 'yourFormName', Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost() );
```

In your phtml template, print the data if 'yourFormName' variable session exist.